# Highcharts - changing one series shifts another

Tags: javascript, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I'm currently building some charts where I'm showing averages and the goal value for this chart, along with the actual value. This works perfectly fine, except when I zoom, I want to replace the data in the average series with the current average.

I'm able to recalculate the average series and add this to the chart as it should. However, for some inexplicable reason this takes the series that comes after this, and moves it 1 point ahead in the series. This doesn't reflect on the chart config (still only has my primary xAxis categories), but it shows differently.

Before zoom:
[image: Before zoom]

After zoom in and out again:
[image: After zoom in and out]

Code snippet:

```
setExtremes: function (e) {
              var current = this;
              setTimeout(function () {
                var dataSeries = current.series[0].data;
                console.log(dataSeries)
                var sum = 0;
                var length = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < dataSeries.length; i++) {
                  if (dataSeries[i].isInside) {
                    length += 1;
                    sum += dataSeries[i].y;
                  }
                }
                $scope.charts[0].series[1].data = []; // Commenting out this and the line below makes the data not shift
                for (var i = 0; i < dataSeries.length; i++) {
                  $scope.charts[0].series[1].data.push(parseFloat((sum / length).toFixed(2))) // Commenting out this and the line above makes the data not shift
                }
              })
            }
```

Any suggestions would be very helpful!

Comment: If you just want to have the simple line, why not to use plotLines instead of adding whole new series? Are you able to post live example of this issue?

Comment: I'm not adding a new series - I'm replacing the data in the existing series. Currently I have series[0], series[1], series[2]. I'm then taking the data from series[0].data, getting the total and dividing by visible series[0].data.length, emptying series[1].data (my "average" line) and adding in new data.